# plot() - 'b' parameter in plot not showing lines connecting points

Tags: r, plot, shiny

I am working on a rather large shiny app. I have been  asked to change the line type of a plot from this app, something that should be very easy (just change the value of the `type` parameter. Namely, I need the `type` to be set to `l`). Using `ggplot`is unfortunately not an option as another plot with a different scale will be superposed to this plot.

When I tried however, it did not work. despite having `type` set to `b`, the dots are not joined by a line (see the second image). When I tried `l` the series does not appear!

The weird thing is that if I use the **exact same code** (for both the UI and the Server) with randomly generated data (see snippet below) in a small ad-hoc app, it works (see first image)!!

I would be so grateful to know what can cause this behaviour and how to solve the issue.

Else, perhaps can you recommend an alternative way of getting the same result?

First Image (as expected):
[image]
Second Image:
[image]
My code is as follows:

```
library(shiny)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
s <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
    # some random data
    correlTs <- rnorm(200,50,2)
    dates <- seq(from=Sys.Date(),to=Sys.Date()+199, by=1)
    dateChar <- as.character(dates)
    rollingCorr <- data.frame(dateChar, correlTs)
    # same code as from larger app
    plot(
      as.Date(rollingCorr[, 1]),
      rollingCorr[, 2],
      type = "b",
      col = "dark blue",
      xlab = "Dates",
      ylab = "Correlation"
    )
  })
})

u <- shinyUI(
  navbarPage(
    "MR Tool",
    navbarMenu(
      "SAA",
      tabPanel("A plot",
        plotOutput("distPlot")))))

shinyApp(server = s, ui = u)
```

Edit: the UI code in the snippet above seems unnecessarily contrived .... it is pasted from the larger project I mention at the beginning of the post. For that larger app, having a `tabPanel` makes sense.

Comment: FYI Although I have tried it yet, ggplot2 does now allow secondary axes - http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/sec_axis.html

Comment: are you sure the code is correct, the ui looks a bit weird,..

Comment: @BigDataScientist You are right that it look a bit weird ... I have edited the post correspondingly. I don't know whether the code is correct, but it runs and produces the expected result. Only it does not work when I integrate it in the larger app.

Comment: I have seen this before - not that long ago - but can't remember what it was. But this is not a repro of the error, it is a repro of what it should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally I post a fix, however in this case we don't have a repro, we have a repro of what *should* work, so I can't be sure I know what is going on.

My best guess is that there are NAs in the data which are preventing the lines from being connected. If you look at the documentation for plot you will see that this is intended behavior. Thus looking at the output from `?lines` you can find this excerpt:

> The coordinates can contain NA values. If a point contains NA in
>   either its x or y value, it is omitted from the plot, and lines are
>   not drawn to or from such points. Thus missing values can be used to
>   achieve breaks in lines.

If this was indeed the issue, then you could try fixing it by adding the line:

```
rollingCorr <- rollingCorr[complete.cases(rollingCorr),]
```

right before you plot the data to remove those missing values. Or instead of `complete.cases`, perhaps a different logical clause that targeted only the columns used in the plot.